# How to find the centroid of a object?

Tags: c++, centroid

I'm working on a project on C++, and I'm having problems trying to find the centroid (coordinates x and y) of a object...

I have an image of 250x250 pixels, this image is white with an object of color black and I need to find the centroid of this black object (this black object is a geometric figure).

I count all black pixels with this:

```
for(i=0; i<high; i++) 
{
    for(j=0; j<width; j++)  
    {
        if(Img->imx[i*width+j]==0)
        {
        c=c+1;
        }                                                   

    }
```

Doing this I get all black pixels in the image. But I don’t know how to find the centroid of the object.

Comment: Why did you make your question worse?

Comment: I'm fixing my translation

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know the formula for the centroid? Or is the problem that you don't know how to write the code that calculates the formula?

Comment: Hi @RaymondChen I found the answer on the next comment...thanks

Comment: Just trying to help you ask better questions, rather than hoping people can figure out what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If the object has uniform density, the centroid can be calculated by calculating average of all coords of black pixels.

```
int c = 0;
double x = 0, y = 0;
for(i=0; i<high; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<width; j++)
    {
        if(Img->imx[i*width+j]==0)
        {
             c=c+1;
             x=x+j;
             y=y+i;
        }
    }
}
if(c>0)
{
    x=x/c;
    y=y/c;
}
```

Comment: @DamarisPeralesOjeda: Don't forget to accept this answer if it helped you,